# PHP login system without a database, sessions is not working?

Tags: php, session, authentication

First of all I won't build a login system that uses a database, I know it's more secure but in this case it's not relevant...

I have three files login.php, admin.php and config.php. The users email and password is stored in variables in config.php. If the user is logging in a session should be set. Then if a user that hasn't logged in trying to access admin.php ":-(" should be printed. But now the ":-(" is always printed and something needs to be wrong with how I coded it all...

config.php:

```
<?php

//site data

$title = "Abbesplace";
$siteurl = "index.php";

//user data
$password = "testtest";
$email = "example@example.com";
$name = "Albin Larsson";
?>
```

login.php:

```
<?php

require_once("config.php");

if (($_POST['email'] == $email && $_POST['password'] == $password)) {
    //login
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['logged']= "welcometomoon";
    header("Location: admin.php");
} else {
    echo "login faild";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="post" action="login.php">
                Email:<input type="email" name="email"/>
                Password:<input type="password" name="password"/>
                <input type="submit"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

admin.php:

```
<?php

if(isset($_SESSION['logged'])){
    echo "Hello";
} else {
    echo ":-(";
}

?>
```

Any suggestions on what I should make different?
(I'm a newbie when i comes to PHP)...

Comment: You need `session_start` in every file where you access $_SESSION - in this case, in admin.php too

Comment: Storing username/passwords in a database is no more or less secure than in flat files or config files. However, storing plain text passwords is always insecure. At the very least, you should store an MD5 or SHA1 hash of the password, then hash the password that gets submitted with the form and compare that to the one on your config file, not the plain password itself. Take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to call session_start on every page. Right now you are only calling it when you post to the login form.